# Agora iOS SDK : showing a loading screen when an audience joins a channel

Tags: ios, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

With Agora iOS SDK, I would like to show a loading screen when an audience is joining a channel. If the host is not broadcasting, I would then like to show a message that host is offline. However, I am not sure which `AgoraRtcEngineDelegate` API I need to use to achieve this.

Here is what I have tried so far.

I tried to use `AgoraVideoRemoteState` which is updated by `remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid` callback when a remote video state changes. I set the initial value of `AgoraVideoRemoteState` to `nil` (showing a loading screen at this point) and updated it to `.decoding` to show a streaming screen if the host is online. However, Agora does not seem to fire `remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid` if the host is offline when the audience joins a channel which is leading to the loading screen not being updated.

Is there any API to identify whether the host is offline when an audience joins a channel.

Thanks in advance!

ref:
`AgoraVideoRemoteState`: https://docs.agora.io/en/live-streaming/API%20Reference/oc/Constants/AgoraVideoRemoteState.html

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that until you get any callback of remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid that there is no host online.
Display the loading screen until you get the `.decoding` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought about that but I wanted to show a different message when the host is actually offline. Showing a loading message forever makes users confused that there may be something wrong with their network connections.

Comment: You could say "Waiting for host..." then on a timeout state "No host found"
If you connect to an RTM channel then you can see how many and which users are online too, sending messages between them. If no other users or no host user is online then you have your answer